# Adding one maven project into another maven project causing Could not resolve dependencies error

Tags: java, maven, repository

I have two projects.
ABC and XYZ .
What I need is to get the ABC classes in XYZ

.For this I have added dependency of ABC into XYZ and did the mvn clean in eclipse. It worked!

but when I did mvn clean install it is showing

```
Failed to execute goal on project XYZ: Could not resolve dependencies
Failure to find ABC-SERVER:ABC:jar:Server in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository.
```

Here is my pom's
ABC's pom.xml:

```
<groupId>abc-server</groupId>
    <artifactId>ABCServer</artifactId>
    <name>ABCServer</name>
    <version>Server</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
```

XYZ's pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>abc-server</groupId>
        <artifactId>ABCServer</artifactId>
        <version>Server</version>
    </dependency>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

What is the way to do this. I need to run mvn clean package from windows command line.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did the same. No luck

Comment: Yes it there in the repo. but it is in war

Comment: version, artifactid and groupId are same. but 1 thing is different: after mvn clean on ABC makes the war file. and from B it is looking for jar file? this can be an issue?

Comment: please check the answer

Answer (score 1):

Look at the error message:

> Failure to find ABC-SERVER:ABC:**jar**:Server

Obviously, it will never find that dependency because no such artifact exists. Your ABC-SERVER is packaged as a war.

You can make it resolve the dependency correctly by adding `<type>war</type>` to the dependency in XYZ, but if XYZ is also a war, this may not be what you want. Maven will *overlay* the ABC-SERVER war on the XYZ war (see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html for more details).

If you just want to reuse the *classes* from the ABC-SERVER webapp, I suppose the correct way to do that is to separate the classes into a new jar artifact and use that in both webapps.

Answer (score 0):

you have to deploy your ABCServer artifact to your remote repository.

a `mvn deploy` on your ABCServer repository should do the trick

Comment: Not necessarily. Maven will also find it if both artifacts are in the reactor (meaning there is a parent pom that includes both ABCServer and XYZ as modules, and you run maven from there), or if it is in the _local_ repository (e.g. you ran `mvn install` on ABCServer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are packaging the project ABC as war. you need to change the packaging to jar..

So change  `<packaging>war</packaging>` to  `<packaging>jar</packaging>`